# Can somebody help me TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnZgO.png)

** This is the file where I am getting the error **

```
import React from "react";
import ChartBar from "./ChartBar";

const Chart = props => {
  const dataPointValues = props.data.map(dataPoint => dataPoint.value);
  const totalMaximum = Math.max(...dataPointValues);

  return (
    <div className="chart">
      {props.data.map(dataPoint => (
        <ChartBar
          key={dataPoint.label}
          value={dataPoint.value}
          maxValue={totalMaximum}
          label={dataPoint.label}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

**This is is the file where I render the component above**

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from "../Chart/Chart";

const ExpensesChart = props => {

    const chartDataPoints = [
        {label: 'Jan', value:0},
        {label: 'Feb', value:0},
        {label: 'Mar', value:0},
        {label: 'Apr', value:0},
        {label: 'May', value:0},
        {label: 'Jun', value:0},
        {label: 'Jul', value:0},
        {label: 'Aug', value:0},
        {label: 'Sep', value:0},
        {label: 'Oct', value:0},
        {label: 'Nov', value:0},
        {label: 'Dec', value:0}
    ];

    for (const expense of props.expenses)
    {
        const expenseMonth = expense.date.getMonth(); //starting at 0 => January => 0
        chartDataPoints[expenseMonth].value += expense.amount;
    }

return (<Chart data={chartDataPoints}/>);
}

export default ExpensesChart;
```

Any help will be appreciate, I have tried everything. This is a course that I am taking I have repeated the video many times and the teacher code and mine look the same. Thanks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-voice-xj68h

Comment: That is not how one should create a sandbox. But, try [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-error-map-of-undefined-wwo1s?file=/src/components/Chart/ChartBar.js) and it works.

Comment: @AjeetShah having the same error with your sandbox

Comment: This is your sandbox look https://pasteboard.co/K2dbCXD.png

Comment: That's strange. It works for me. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. In such case, I would try many things - check on different browser, different laptop, or try mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you can do to check why it is `undefined` is by using the Chrome Devtool breakpoint and see `Chart` component's data props is an array or not and solve the root cause why it is `undefined`.

Otherwise, to avoid this kind of **TypeError**, the least you can do is to put **&&** expression to check if `props.data` is an array like this.

```
import React from "react";
import ChartBar from "./ChartBar";

const Chart = props => {
  const dataPointValues = Array.isArray(props?.data) && props.data.map(dataPoint => 
    dataPoint.value);
  const totalMaximum = Array.isArray(dataPointValues) && Math.max(...dataPointValues);

  return (
    <div className="chart">
      {Array.isArray(props?.data) && props.data.map(dataPoint => (
        <ChartBar
          key={dataPoint.label}
          value={dataPoint.value}
          maxValue={totalMaximum}
          label={dataPoint.label}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Comment: Still having the same issue

Comment: please provide failing sandbox ... https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-voice-xj68h is not failing... it is not even pointed to Chart.js file.